# How can I express in sed to 'print from the line following the first occurrence of a pattern, exclusively'?

Tags: sed

When I have the input:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Sat Jul  1 09:28:03 UTC 2023 - Matej Cepl <mcepl@suse.com>

- Clean up SPEC file.

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Mon Jul  4 18:11:38 UTC 2022 - Matej Cepl <mcepl@suse.com>

- Do not unset various variables when calling make (only CFLAGS
  should be set).
```

I would like to receive only the following as output:

```
- Clean up SPEC file.

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Mon Jul  4 18:11:38 UTC 2022 - Matej Cepl <mcepl@suse.com>

- Do not unset various variables when calling make (only CFLAGS
  should be set).
```

Comment: What is your matching criteria - a line starting with a date? Your question title isn't clear

Answer (score 1):

Simply invert your logic: delete lines no. 1 to pattern match (inclusive)

```
sed '1,/PATTERN/d' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed '0,/pattern/d' inputfile.txt`

- `0,/pattern/` matches from the beginning of the file
- `pattern/d` deletes the matched line and all subsequent lines before

`sed '0,/Sat/d' inputfile.txt`

Redirect output to new file:

`sed '0,/Sat/d' input.txt > outputfile.txt`

Comment: Note that `0` as address is a GNU-extention and not POSIX.